# Check in php if a view display exists?

Tags: views

I've created a display called 'stats' for some views I've created - its cached and its generic and its quick and I use it for things like this

```
$result = views_get_view_result($view_name,'stats'); 
$count = count($result);
if ($count) $variables['title'] .= ' ('.$count.')';
```

However, not all views have this display. 
How can I check, in php, if a given view has a display called 'stats' ?

Answer (score 5):

Off the cuff, this should work:

```
$view = views_get_view($view_name);
if ($view && $view->access('stats')) {
  // it has a 'stats' display
  $view->set_display('stats');
  $view->pre_execute();
  $view->execute();
  return $view->result; // or do whatever with it...
}
```

but realize at this point you're halfway through the 'heavy lifting' views does, so you should probably use `$view` inside that `if` instead of then calling `views_get_view_result()`

ADDITION:  I added what I think the correct `$view` incantations should be for getting just the results above :)

Answer (score 0):

First make a **views_get_view($view_name);** it will give you the $view object, which I'm sure will tell you which display it has. Then you'll be able to if().